# python pickle.loads(data) leads to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'

Tags: python, pickle

picture of code error in visual studio code:
[image]

I can't get past this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'". I've tried finding ways to resolve this but wasn't able to solve it. Please helpp

Comment: Unpickling requires access to the modules that defined *every* object contained in the pickled data.  Apparently there was a class definition in a file named client.py, that you don't have (at least not in the right location, or not with the right name).

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.